# ADOBE AIR FOR Android

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe

My son is starting to write some Android apps using Java, which they are teaching at school.
I saw some interesting videos from Adobe MAX online that showed a car spinning around using 1% of the CPU, instead using the GPU for the processing.

Q: Where do I point my son to tell him there are alternatives to Java?
I need something to help him write a Hello World application on the Android, but include graphics, sound, touch, geo-location, etc, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The car demo you're talking about was using something called Molehill, which is the code-name for Adobe's upcoming 3D expansion for Flash. It's not available anywhere yet, it's in very early pre-release.

That's different from Adobe AIR for Android, which is a packager for AIR application to allow them to run on Android Devices. Adobe also offers AIR for iPhone, which allows you to package your AIR applications to run on iOS devices.

There are two schools of thought on mobile application development. One says, learn the native code style. If you want an Android app, learn the Java APIs. If you want an iPhone app, learn the Objective C APIs. There are advantages to this approach.

However, if you're more interested in creating stuff using the Flash toolbox (which lets you build really powerful things really quickly), AIR for mobile devices is worth considering. Not only to get to use Flash for your development, but you can deploy to multiple endpoints from the same codebase. This is a huge advantage moving forward, though it's not quite as simple as "check the box for iphone" vs "check the box for android."

If your son wants to get into programming, Java is a perfectly good way to do it but as a professional Flash developer I'm happy to encourage him to dive into AIR, as you suggest here. The best resources are going to be at Adobe's site, but I do know that Lee Brimelow has a LOT of great Flash tutorials at gotoandlearn.com - I'm pretty sure he has one that will step you through creating an AIR for Android app, publishing it and sending it to the Android Marketplace. All in about 20 minutes. Worth a look!

This website seems to have a LOT of resources for AIR for Android, including various case studies:

http://blogs.adobe.com/air/2010/04/adobe_air_applications_for_and.html

Comment: +1.  Molehill is going to be insane!  Lee Brimelow recently posted a video interview with Thibault Imbert about Molehill that's worth checking out:  http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=2468

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html
in this site there are very good tutorials for beginners!!Good Luck and a Happy New Year

Comment: you can also see the hello views and all the tutorials in the developers.android

Comment: Could you please expand on your answer, as link-only answers are discouraged and might be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

[AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) is a very interesting and free Open Source 2D OpenGL Game Engine for the Android platform. A friend of mine has been using it for a bit of a time, and he very quickly got some cool small games up and running using that.

Go to the AndEngine home page to read the blog and look at the source, or download [the example app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/andengine-examples/org.anddev.andengine.examples) to your phone to see what it can do.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that nobody has mentioned the App-Inventor. Created by Google, App-Inventor is set to encourage younger ones pick up the essential logical thinking of programming. It offers a graphic GUI and tools for implementing complex logics.

http://www.appinventorbeta.com/about/

I would say it is a nice tool for secondary school students and even non-computer-science undergraduates who wants to understand programming mobile applications.